# Automate FTP of files (csv) to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want to automate the data uploading/ingestion to Amazon S3 bucket. I don't want to use softwares like Filezilla for FTP to S3.

The files will be available to FTP server on daily basis.
I want to pick those files from FTP server and store in Amazon S3 on daily basis.
Can i set up cron jobs or scripts to run in AWS in a cost-effective manner.
What AWS instances can help me in achieving this.

The files are approx 1GB of size.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, do you want to upload files to s3? If yes, from where?

Comment: Why do you wish to use FTP? What do you mean by "pulled" -- from where would they be "pulled"? Are they being "pulled" from an FTP server? What will be done with the files once they are in S3? Please edit your question to tell us more about your _actual_ goals (eg _What_ you want to achieve, rather than _How_) so that we can help you find the best way to achieve your goals.

Comment: @AllanChua The file source is a FTP server. Daily data will be uploaded to a FTP server by other team (located in a different country) and I need to get that data and upload in S3 on daily basis.

Comment: Is there an actual programming question here? Because all of the "questions" can be answered simply by looking at Amazon's docs, sometimes even from the marketing pages (eg scheduling and Lambdas). The *real* programming questions aren't asked at all - how to download files from FTP programmatically, how to use the S3 API

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, the files will be pulled from a FTP server. 

My goal is to:
- Get the data periodically and store it in S3 for further analysis using Tableau/QuickSight.

Comment: `in a cost-effective manner` that means different things to different people or different scenarios. Scheduled jobs are charged by the execution but don't incur the cost of a VM, nor do you have to write the code to manage and run them. Which one is more cost effective depends on what you want to do. If you have to run lots of jobs very often, the scheduling service may be too expensive in the long run. If not, the VM may be more expensive. But, if you have a VM you can run as many jobs as you like instead of paying for Lambdas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon S3 is an object storage service. It cannot "pull" data from an external location.

Therefore, you will need a script or program that will:

- Retrieve the data from the FTP server, and
- Upload the data to Amazon S3

It would be best to run such a script from the FTP server itself, so that the data can be sent to S3 without having to download from the FTP server first. If this is not possible, then you could run the script on any computer on the Internet, such as your own computer or an Amazon EC2 instance.

The simplest way to upload to Amazon S3 is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It has a `aws s3 cp` command to copy files, or depending upon what needs to be copied it might be easier to use the `aws s3 sync` command that automatically copies new or modified files.

The script could be triggered via a schedule (cron on Linux or a Scheduled Task on Windows).

If you are using an Amazon EC2 instance, you could save money by turning off the instance when it is not required. The flow could be:

- Create an **Amazon CloudWatch Event rule** that triggers an AWS Lambda function
- The **AWS Lambda function** can call `StartInstances()` to start a stopped EC2 instance
- The **Amazon EC2 instance** can use a startup script (see details below) that will run your process
- At the end of the process, tell the operating system to shutdown (`sudo shutdown now -h`)

This might seem like a lot of steps, but the CloudWatch Event and Lambda function are trivial to configure.

To execute a script *every time a Linux instance starts*, put it in: `/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/`

See also: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Comment: Thanks @John. But I dont have a server to run cron job on.
So I was planning to use cron jobs to start/stop EC2 instance, which will in turn fetch my data.
I know that AWS Lambda can be used to trigger start/stop of EC2 instance. Is there any other AWS services too, to achieve this?